# SQL query based on values from another tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I need to put external courses to "ext" folder.
Which course is external? -External course is course whose vendor doesn't have a client_id.
So first we check if vendor for our course has a client_id, we will check for that in vendor table. If our vendor doesn't have client_id (client_id = NULL) then we want to grab an ID of "ext" record from folder table and insert it to folder_id column. If our vendor has a client_id we dont do anything, so second row in course table under folder_id will be empty. Folder_id column should be populated like this: 1.row = 2, 2.row = (empty), 3.row = 2, 4.row = 2, 5.row = 2.

Here is the code that I have for now but I'm getting 'column reference "id" is ambiguous' at line 2. I dont know if code is good, I'm not that good with sql.
(prefix 't' in code means table)

```
UPDATE t_course SET folder_id = (SELECT id FROM t_folder WHERE code IS NULL)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM t_course course
                JOIN t_vendor vendor ON vendor.id = course.vendor_id
                WHERE vendor.client_id IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you really want `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE t_course c
    SET folder_id = (SELECT f.id FROM t_folder f WHERE f.code IS NULL)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM  t_vendor vendor 
              WHERE v.id = c.vendor_id AND v.client_id IS NULL
             );
```

Comment: thank you, that was what i needed. I would upvote your answer but I cant, dont have enough reputation.